# Is there any way of adding Chinese characters to AutoKey?

Tags: autokey

Each time I add Chinese characters to AutoKey and set an autokey. The just don't show up in the output.

Does anyone know a way of including them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The autokey program, as packaged and is available in Ubuntu, does not support Unicode strings. It should be possible to make it support Unicode, however this would require changes to the source code.

Since Autokey does not support Unicode, it does not support Chinese either.

Comment: This is the only thing I would use Autokey for. Replacing _bul with • or _deg with °
Are there any libraries I could import to support unicode?