# System-wide text replacement similar to AutoHotKey

Tags: python, automation, unicode, unicode-entry, autokey

**AutoHotKey has this text-replacement feature:**

```
;bullet
::_bullet::•

;disapproval
::_dis::{U+0CA0}_{U+0CA0}

;lenny
::_lenny::( {U+0361}{U+00B0}  {U+035C}{U+0296} {U+0361}{U+00B0}  )
```

**I am trying to replicate this functionality in Ubuntu.**

I have installed [Autokey](https://code.google.com/p/autokey/), and am trying to replace the text, "_bul" with "•". Autokey comes with some sample scripts (python), such as:

```
output = system.exec_command("date")
keyboard.send_keys(output)
```

This prints out the date. I tried:

```
print "•"
```

which works in python, but [apparently](https://askubuntu.com/a/23335/21900), Autokey doesn't support unicode.

**Are there any other tools I could use to achieve this functionality?**

Comment: **xdotool** supports unicode. But, i am unable to make it work like AHK (still working on it)

Answer (score 0):

Try sinippy: http://leon.vankammen.eu/tech/snippy-autocompletion-for-console-and-browser-window-manager-using-bash.html

or snippely:  https://code.google.com/p/snippely/

Other answers on SO might also be helpful to you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175501/best-way-to-manage-code-snippets-in-linux